# Regarding encrypting a song

Tags: c++, c

I want to encrypt an eminem song into a file in such a way that it cannot be decrypted. And i want to use it as a hash to encrypt my password.

How should i go about it in C or C++? What APIs can i use in Windows/Linux.

Comment: Nobody would want to decrypt an eminem song anyway. In the past that kind of "singing" was called stuttering and was curable.</music-nazi>

Comment: If you never want to be able to decrypt the file, just overwrite it with random bits.

Comment: -1 for being very vague. "cannot be decrypted" - then use a hash like SHA1. "use it as a hash to encrypt my password" - how is that related to embedding it into another file

Comment: Encryption kinda assumes decryption, it appears you want hashing which is a different thing. Are you intending on using the hash as the key for your encrypted password?

Comment: Create the encrypted file by `and`ing each byte of the input with hex `0x00`.  I guarantee the output cannot be decrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google around for password managers.

Some (keepass eg) will even allow you to use a key file.

If you wanted to use a keyfile to generate a password, may I suggest doing it yourself like so:

```
cat eminem.mp3
 | openssl dgst -sha1 -binary -hmac password \
 | openssl enc -base64 \
 | cut -c 1-8
```

Replace 'password' by something stronger; this way you can use different passwords, all deterministically generated from the same keyfile